# Kruskal-Wallis or Friedman's test?

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

I'm really confused about which test to use to test the hyposthesis; "There is no difference in the preference of an exercise programme". Each participant (n=17) attends all three different exercise sessions (aqua aerobics, step aerobics, and circuit training). The 'enjoyment score' is given by each participant and is out of 100.

I know it's ordinal level data so need a non-parametric test. But I'm not sure if it's classed as independent samples, as comparing three different groups (Kruskal-Wallis test), or repeated measures (Friedman test) because the same person is involved in each exercise type?!

Please can someone clarify??

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have data in 3 columns (aqua aerobics, step aerobics, and circuit training) and each row represents data for one person.

In this case, you should use the Friedman's test, and afterwards paired Wilcoxon signed-rank tests (for post-hoc testing).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did think it was Friedman's but wanted to check.

Comment: Note that the Wilcoxon signed-rank (WSR) test is somewhat inconsistent with the Friedman test.   WSR is an efficient test (but only handles a single difference, not 3 columns) whereas Friedman's test is a generalization of the inefficient _sign test_ so is not so powerful.